# What is the first non zero digit in 50 factorial (50!)?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the first non zero digit in 50 factorial (50!)?

Any Help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: its a 2 (counting form right to left, or a 3 =

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: how to write the equivalent symbol in latex?
i have an answer and working for this.

Comment: @ManojPandey you mean $\equiv$ that is \equiv

Comment: @DominicMichaelis thanks

Comment: Since you accepted the answer that computes the _last_ nonzero digit, I suppose you meant that; you might want to change the question to match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the exponent of $2$ in $50!$ is $47$, and the exponent of $5$ in $50!$ is $12$, so we’re looking for $\frac{50!}{10^{12}}$ mod$ 10$.

---

Since $\frac{50!}{10^{12}}$ is even (in fact, divisible by $2^{35}$), it suffices to compute it mod $5$:

$\frac{50!}{5^{12}}$ $\equiv$ ($4!$. $1$. $4!$. $2$. $4!$. $3$. $4!$. $4$. $4!$. $1$.($4!$. $1$. $4!$. $2$. $4!$. $3$. $4!$. $4$. $4!$). $2$

=$4!^{10}$.$4!^2$.2!

$\equiv$$(-1)^{10}$.$(-1)^2$.2

$\equiv$ $2$ mod $5$

$\frac{50}{10^{12}}$ $\equiv$ $2$.$2^{-12}$ $\equiv$ $2$ . $(2^4)^{-3}$ $\equiv$ $2$ mod $5$

---

So, $\frac{50!}{5^{12}}$ $\equiv$ $2$ (mod $10$ )

Comment: "Since $\frac{50!}{10^12}$ is even" should be replaced by "Since $\frac{50!}{10^{12}}$ is even"...Please edit.

Answer (score 8):

Since $50_{\text{ten}}=200_{\text{five}}$, $\sigma_5(50)=2$. Thus, the number of factors of $5$ in $50!$ is $\frac{50-2}{5-1}=12$.

Since $50_{\text{ten}}=110010_{\text{two}}$, $\sigma_2(50)=3$. Thus, the number of factors of $2$ in $50!$ is $\frac{50-3}{2-1}=47$.

Thus, $\frac{50!}{10^{12}}$ has $35$ factors of $2$.

Little Fermat says that $2^4\equiv1\pmod{5}$, so $2\cdot2^4\equiv2\pmod{10}$, therefore $2^{35}\equiv2\cdot2^{34}\equiv2\cdot2^2\equiv8\pmod{10}$.

---

Every integer is uniquely representable as $m\cdot2^j\cdot5^k$ where $(m,10)=1$.

Let's compute the product $\bmod{\,10}$ of all of the numbers $m$ so that $(m,10)=1$ and $m\cdot2^j\cdot5^k\le50$, grouped by $2^j\cdot5^k$:

$\overbrace{(1\cdot3\cdot7\cdot9)^5}^{1}\overbrace{(1\cdot3\cdot7\cdot9)^2(1\cdot3)}^{2}\overbrace{(1\cdot3\cdot7\cdot9)^1(1)}^{4}\overbrace{(1\cdot3)^{\vphantom{1}}}^{8}\overbrace{(1\cdot3)^{\vphantom{1}}}^{16}\overbrace{(1)^{\vphantom{1}}}^{32}\\
\overbrace{(1\cdot3\cdot7\cdot9)^1}^{5}\overbrace{(1\cdot3)^{\vphantom{1}}}^{10}\overbrace{(1)^{\vphantom{1}}}^{20}\overbrace{(1)^{\vphantom{1}}}^{40}\\
\overbrace{(1)^{\vphantom{1}}}^{25}\overbrace{(1)^{\vphantom{1}}}^{50}\\
\equiv(1\cdot3\cdot7\cdot9)^9(1\cdot3)^4\equiv9\pmod{10}$

---

Thus, $\frac{50!}{10^{12}}\equiv8\cdot9\equiv2\pmod{10}$.

Comment: thorough and good explanation

Comment: Won't this give the **last** non-zero digit?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: That depends from which side you are counting. The boundary between the non-zero digits of $n!$ and the string of $0$s to the right is the lowest order or rightmost non-zero digit, I figured that is what the OP meant. The highest order or leftmost digit is easily computed using Stirling's formula to be $3$. See also [Marc van Leeuwen's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341578/what-is-the-first-non-zero-digit-in-50-factorial-50/341726#comment735478_341578)

Answer (score 4):

The obvious method is to compute $50!$ and look at its digits (there's not that many of them).  Here it is:

> 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000

This is fairly straightforward to do on a computer (as long as you're alert for numerical overflow).  This method also has the benefits of (a) giving you all the other digits too, which helps you cross-check that the answer is correct, (b) being less likely to incur human error, and (c) will be more scaleable than human-operated methods.

In [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50!), we can input `50!` to obtain:

[image: Wolfram|Alpha computation of $50!$]

I personally prefer to use [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/).  In GAP, we input `Factorial(50);` to obtain:

```
gap> Factorial(50);
30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
```

Or if we're feeling industrious, we might whip up some code to compute the last non-zero digit of $n!$ for all $n \in \{1,2,\ldots,100\}$.

```
for n in [1..100] do
  N:=Factorial(n);
  str:=DigitsNumber(N,10);
  i:=Size(str);
  while(str[i]='0') do
    i:=i-1;
  od;
  Print(n," ",Int([str[i]]),"\n");
od;
```

We can put these numbers into Sloane's On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, and discover it's sequence [A008904](http://oeis.org/A008904).  Here we can learn all sorts of things about these numbers, along with code for SAGE, Python, Mathematica and PARI (much more efficient than mine above).